# Толстый конструктор

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования

В результате проведенного рефакторинга получился класс-хелпер, с толстым конструктором, в котором происходит куча вычислений на основании данных, пполученных из других стандартных классов-хелперов.

Коструктор не имеет парамтеров и их введение является контрпродуктивнным, т.к. класс инстанцируется фрейморком, DI которого [не может передать парамтеры в конструктор](https://git.io/vKWQb).

Является ли укзанная "толстота" конструктора приемлемым решением?

Comment: Всё зависит от конкретного случая. Можно хоть ультратолстые методы делать - если ты уверен что никакому программисту-пользователю твоих методов не потребуется чуть-чуть изменить работу метод, не трогая твой код (это делается наследованием).

Comment: На мой взгляд, конструктор, это таки не совсем то место, куда помещают "кучу вычислений". Конструкторы таки обычно предназначены для инициализации значений, необходимых поведению, реализуемому классом.

Comment: так дело в том, что выносить некуда логику